# Veracode Upload API is not displaying the composite action : uploadandscan

Tags: veracode

I have gone through the VeraCode API Wrapper documentation details.  I followed all the steps related to “Referencing the Veracode API Wrapper from Visual Studio”.

Based on the steps, I was able to create an instance of UploadAPIWrapper class as mentioned below:

var uploadWrapper = new UploadAPIWrapper();

I was able to see all the simple actions the wrapper can perform as mentioned below:

[image]

I was also able to see the composite action uploadandscan in the command prompt also as mentioned in the screenshot below:
[image]

But was not able to see the composite actions the wrapper can perform like uploadandscan.

Can anyone please advise me here in case I am missing out any prequisites.

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro

Answer (score 0):

What you would normally pass when you call the UploadAndScan action from the command line would look more or less like this:

VeracodeC#API.exe -action uploadandscan -appname appName -version version -createprofile true -filepath filePath -vuser username -vpassword password

So for your code to work you would need to modify it as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using com.veracode.apiwrapper;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
using System;
{
    static void Main()
    {
        //----------------------------------------------------------
        String appName =        "enter-application-name-here";
        String version =        "enter-version-here";
        bool createProfile =    true;//or false;
        String filePath =       "enter-filepath-here";//ie: "C:\\file.exe"

        String username =       "enter-username-here";
        String password =       "enter-password-here";
        //----------------------------------------------------------

        //String[] args = <the same args that you pass when you call the UploadAndScan composite action>;
        String[] args = new String[]
        {
            "-action", "uploadandscan",
            "-appname", appName,
            "-version", version,
            "-createprofile", createProfile.ToString(),
            "-filepath", filePath,
            "-vuser", username,
            "-vpassword", password
        };

        Type t = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(AbstractAPIWrapper)).GetType("com.veracode.apiwrapper.cli.VeracodeCommand");
        MethodInfo m = t.GetMethod("Main", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);
        m.Invoke(null, new Object[] { args });

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Based on your suggestion I used the following , but still I am getting the value of methodInfo as null.The following is the code:  string[] argsList = new string[] { "appname", "createprofile", "filepath", "version", "vpassword", "vuser" };
            Type type = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(UploadAPIWrapper)).GetType("com.veracode.apiwrapper.cli.VeracodeCommand");
            MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("uploadandscan", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
            methodInfo.Invoke(null, new Object[] { argsList });